# Discord.py discord bot loop function works only for one server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a problem with a looping function in my discord.py bot. I want music to be played at a specific time on every connected server. My code works by checking that the time is right, then finds the first voice channel on the server with some users, joins it, plays music and disconnects. My problem is that it only joins the first server on the "guilds" list, the one it was invited to first. Is there any way to get the bot to work on all the servers it is invited to, not just the first one?

Here is code of looped function:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 5)
async def loop():
   
    guilds = client.guilds
    print (guilds)
    for guild in guilds:
        voice_channel_list = guild.voice_channels
        for i in range(len(voice_channel_list)):
            channel = client.get_channel(voice_channel_list[i].id)
            curMembers = []
            for member in channel.members:
                curMembers.append(member)
            if (len(curMembers) > 0 and datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")=="22:22"):
                await channel.connect()
                voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=guild)
                if(randrange(1,100) <= 30):
                    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source="sounds/music1.mp3"))
                    while voice.is_playing():
                        await sleep(1)
                    await voice.disconnect()
                else:
                    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source="sounds/music2.mp3"))
                    while voice.is_playing():
                        await sleep(1)
                    await voice.disconnect()

                break
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i think the problem in your code is that you are breaking out of the for loop that goes through all the guilds so you need to remove the unwanted break statement at line 28 and it should work like a charm.

Comment: removing "break" helped only partially, now the bot joins other servers, but when it joins one server, it does not join the other, as if it was waiting for the end of music playback on one server and then wanted to go to the next one.